# Issue compiling after upgrading to Antlr4 4.6.4

Tags: antlr4

We just upgraded our VS project from 4.6.4 to 4.6.6 of Antlr4. When we rebuild we get the following error message (detailed output from build log).

```
2>Using "Antlr4ClassGenerationTask" task from assembly "E:\Development\Martin\SCADA\STEAM\packages\Antlr4.CodeGenerator.4.6.6\build\..\tools\net40\Antlr4BuildTasks.dll".
2>Task "Antlr4ClassGenerationTask" (TaskId:144)
2>  Task Parameter:OutputPath=obj\Release\ (TaskId:144)
2>  Task Parameter:GenerateVisitor=True (TaskId:144)
2>  Task Parameter:LanguageSourceExtensions=.cs (TaskId:144)
2>  Task Parameter:TargetLanguage=CSharp (TaskId:144)
2>  Task Parameter:JavaVendor=JavaSoft (TaskId:144)
2>  Task Parameter:
2>      SourceCodeFiles=
2>          E:\Development\Martin\All Projects Common\AllProjects.Common\AllProjects.Common\SubstitutionEngine\SubstitutionEngineEvaluator.g4
2>                  Abstract=false
2>                  CopyToOutputDirectory=Never
2>                  CustomToolNamespace=AllProjects.Common
2>                  Encoding=UTF-8
2>                  ForceAtn=false
2>                  Generator=MSBuild:Compile
2>                  Listener=true
2>                  TargetLanguage=CSharp
2>                  Visitor=true (TaskId:144)
2>  Task Parameter:ForceAtn=False (TaskId:144)
2>  Task Parameter:JavaInstallation=Java Runtime Environment (TaskId:144)
2>  Task Parameter:GenerateListener=True (TaskId:144)
2>  Task Parameter:ToolPath=..\tools\antlr4-csharp-4.6.6-complete.jar (TaskId:144)
2>  Task Parameter:Encoding=UTF-8 (TaskId:144)
2>  Task Parameter:TargetNamespace=AllProjects.Common (TaskId:144)
2>E:\Development\Martin\SCADA\STEAM\packages\Antlr4.CodeGenerator.4.6.6\build\Antlr4.CodeGenerator.targets(152,7): error MSB4064: The "UseCSharpGenerator" parameter is not supported by the "Antlr4ClassGenerationTask" task loaded from assembly: Antlr4BuildTasks, Version=4.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=09abb75b9ed49849 from the path: E:\Development\Martin\SCADA\STEAM\packages\Antlr4.CodeGenerator.4.6.4\tools\net40\Antlr4BuildTasks.dll. Verify that the parameter exists on the task, the <UsingTask> points to the correct assembly, and it is a settable public instance property.
2>E:\Development\Martin\SCADA\STEAM\packages\Antlr4.CodeGenerator.4.6.6\build\Antlr4.CodeGenerator.targets(132,5): error MSB4063: The "Antlr4ClassGenerationTask" task could not be initialized with its input parameters.
2>Done executing task "Antlr4ClassGenerationTask" -- FAILED. (TaskId:144)
```

The error can be seen on the 3rd and 2nd to last lines in the log. I checked and we do not set 'UseCSharpGenerator' anywhere, nor do we set .

I am not sure why all of a sudden the Antlr4 engine decides to load a 4.6.4 assembly. Everywhere else in the log, 4.6.6 assemblies have been loaded correctly. This place is the first time a 4.6.4 assembly is referenced.

I have tried uninstalling the packages (Antrl4, CodeGenerator and RunTime) and reinstalling, but I keep running into the same issue.

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: It seems that what you're actually using is antlr4cs, Tunnel Vision Labs' optimized for C# generation version of ANTLR. It seems that UseCSharpGenerator does not exist in v4.6.4 (https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4cs/blob/v4.6.4/runtime/CSharp/Antlr4BuildTasks/Antlr4ClassGenerationTask.cs) but it does exist in v4.6.6 (https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4cs/blob/v4.6.6/runtime/CSharp/Antlr4BuildTasks/Antlr4ClassGenerationTask.cs). So 4.6.6 might get loaded, partially (? if this is even possible)...

Comment: It could be. I just did the NuGet update from 4.6.4 to 4.6.6. Yeah, it is really strange why 4.6.4 assemblies would get involved here.